# How do I edit a file currently being used by vi?

Tags: linux, vim, vi

I am new to Linux and trying out Ubuntu 11.10. I am setting up a SSH server and one of the instructions asks me to edit sshd_config file using vi.

In vi, I can't remember what happen (it's all a blur now) but the up/down keys turn into capital alphabets. After a bit, I give up, search on SO, and the solution is to use vim, not vi. So I try to exit vi (didn't' remember what I did) but I got back to the console.

Then, when I enter sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config it says a swap file exist. Using ls -A only lists the sshd_config and I don't see a ssh_confid.swp file anywhere.

```
ps -ef | grep vi
```

shows this:

```
root      2914  2135  0 10:45 pts/0    00:00:00 sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
root      2915  2914  0 10:45 pts/0    00:00:00 vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
user       4066  2135  0 11:28 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto vi
```

Then so I try to kill the processes, by using sudo kill 2135 2914 2915 and nothing happens. HOw do I get out of this mess?

THanks.

Comment: In Ubuntu Linux, `vi` and `vim` are the same program, but one is a symbolic link to the other (and `vi` actually sets some old vi-style keys I think). The `.swp` file is a vim thing, and you can see it in `/etc/ssh/` by typing `ls -a`, which will show hidden files. You can delete the swp file, or use an editor like pico/nano.

Comment: In such a condition, you can remove the swp file by hitting `D` when you get the message.

Answer (score 2):

First off, if

```
sudo kill <pid>
```

does not kill a process after several attempts, try

```
sudo kill -9 <pid>.
```

That will force the process to end.

Next, execute a

```
ls -a /etc/ssh | grep ".swp"
```

to look for any swap files.  You'll probably find a file called ".sshd_config.swp", so you'll want to delete that before trying to edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

```
sudo rm /etc/ssh/.sshd_config.swp
```

If you want to learn more about Vim, here are some links to Vim tutorials.  However, I would recommend `nano` for someone who is brand new to Linux.

[The Interactive Vim Tutorial](http://lifehacker.com/5844890/the-interactive-vim-tutorial-teaches-you-how-to-use-the-super+efficient-vim-text-editor)

[Graphical vi-vim Cheat Sheet and Tutorial](http://www.viemu.com/a_vi_vim_graphical_cheat_sheet_tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can exit `vim` without saving by typing <kbd>:q!</kbd>.
If you want to save the file, type <kbd>:wq</kbd> or <kbd>:x</kbd>.
The `swp` file created by `vim` is a hidden file begin with `.`(dot).
I hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the process listing, you got into a subshell.  If you type `exit` in the shell you were first in, then you should get back to the `vi` session.  Then you can either continue editing in `vi` or exit and run a more intuitive, less powerful editor like `nano` as romainl suggests.

Answer (score -1):

The solution to the underlying problem is to use `nano` or Gedit, if you have access to a GUI, instead of `vi` or `vim`. Vi and Vim are two (related) complex and powerful programs not really suited for beginners.

It's certainly useful to learn Vi(m)'s basics if you intend to spend a lot of time coding in Linux (or elsewhere) but don't bother trying to learn it for editing a few lines every blue moon.

The solution to the immediate problem is:

```
$ sudo killall vi
```

which is going to kill all running instances of `vi` after asking for your password.

After you are done, use the same commands you used but replacing `vi` with `nano` which is a  lot less powerful and a lot more intuitive with its menu at the bottom.

```
$ sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```